# How to tag documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, collections, tags, lookup

I need to tag documents in a collection, let's call it 'Contacts'.

The first idea I had was to create an attribute called "tags" for each document.
Well, in this case we have something like:

```
{
_id:'1',
contact_name:'Asya Kamsky',
tags:['mongodb', 'maths', 'travels']
}
```

Now, let's suppose that we have users that want to tag any document in 'Contacts'.

If we keep the decision to save the tags attribute for each document, as the tags are personal, we need to use the userId for each tag.
So our document would be something like that (or not):

```
{
_id:'1',
contact_name:'Asya Kamsky',
tags:[
{userId:'alex',tags:['mongodb', 'maths', 'travels']},
{userId:'eric',tags:['databases', 'friends', 'japan']},
]
}
```

Now, let's complicate it a bit. Let's imagine that we have A LOT of users and each one want to tag documents with his personal tags.

How to deal with that?

Ok, we could create thousands of tags for each document:

```
{
_id:'1',
contact_name:'Asya Kamsky',
tags:[
{userId:'alex',tags:['mongodb', 'maths', 'travels']},
{userId:'eric',tags:['databases', 'friends', 'japan']},
{.....................................................}
{.....................................................}
{......................................................}
]
}
```

But, what if we have millions of users? In this case we have a 16mg limitation for each document, as I know....

At this point, worrying about the future growth of my application, I decided
to create a nice separated collection called 'tags' that would contain documents similar to:

```
{
    "contact_name" : "Asya Kamsky",
    "useriId" : "alex",
    "tags" : ['mongodb', 'maths', 'travels'],
    "timestamp" : "2017-08-08 14:33:28"
},

{
    "contact_name" : "Asya Kamsky",
    "useriId" : "eric",
    "tags" : ['databases', 'friends', 'japan'],
    "timestamp" : "2017-08-08 14:33:28"
}
```

That's, we have a separated documents that represent a tag of each user.

Cool and clean, right?

Well, i this case, we face 2 problems:

1. Minor problem: We return to the SQL logic that I don't like anymore but I accept in some cases.
2. Big (for me) problem: how to search a contact by PERSONAL tags? In this case we have a nice 'JOIN' problem that MongoDB resolves well using $lookup. 
   "Resolves well" for 10000, 20000, or even 500000 documents. But as I want to ensure a good performance in the future, I think about 10000000 contacts. So, as I researched recently, the $lookup works well for a "small part" of universe and, even with indexes, this search would take a lot of time to be executed.

How to resolve this challenge?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

If your usage is such that the `number of users` X `number/size of tags` per contact (plus whatever other data is in a `contacts` document) is likely to bring you near the 16MB document size limit then storing the tags ins a separate collection seems valid. But before you go down that route are you sure this is likely? Have you tried creating contact documents in a bid to see how many tags, how many users per contact would get you near the 16MB limit. If the answer implies a number of users and/or tags which you are unlikely ever to reach then maybe your concerns are strictly theoretical and you could consider sticking with the simplest solution which is to embed the user specific tags inside `contacts`.

The rest of this answer assumes that the size estimates and your knowledge about the likely number of tags and users per contact are such that the size constraints are valid. On this basis, you stated this specific concern about join performance ...

> But as I want to ensure a good performance in the future, I think about 10000000 contacts. So, as I researched recently, the $lookup works well for a "small part" of universe and, even with indexes, this search would take a lot of time to be executed.

Have you tried measuring this performance? Generate seed documents for `contacts` and `tags` and then persist variations of these and then run queries using $lookup and measure the performance. You could do this for a few benchmarks, for example:

- 1,000 contacts and 10,000 tags
- 100,000 contacts and 1,000,000 tags
- 1,000,000 contacts and 10,000,000 tags
- 10,000,000 contacts and 100,000,000 tags

When running your benchmark tests you can additionally use `explain()` to understand what's going on inside MongoDB.

You might find that performance is acceptable, only you can know this since you understand what expectations the users of your system have with respect to performance.

One last point, if the use case here is that a given user wants to find all of their contacts and tags then this *could* be handled with a 'client side join' i.e. two queries (1) to get the tags for `"userId" : "..."` and (2) to find the contacts referenced by those tags. Depending on what your use cases are, this *could* be more performant that a server side join (aka $lookup).